# how to redraw custom view from the controller in ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, redraw, custom-view

I have a custom view with 3 buttons taking full width.

I import the class to my controller where I want to hide on button (menuBtn) and make one of the one of the other buttons (searchbarBtn) be bigger to fill the empty space by doing:

```
`self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn.frame.origin.x, self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn.frame.origin.x, self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn.frame.size.width + self.topMenuView.menuBtn.frame.size.width , self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn.frame.size.height);`
```

I do this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (have also tried in `viewWillAppear`) and I call the

`[self.topMenuView.searchbarBtn setNeedsDisplay];`

but nothings happens.

I

Comment: what you want to do ??

Answer (score 0):

The button's layout properties override your frame settings, since by definition `viewWillLayoutSubvies` is called *before* the layout pass. You should just set

```
self.topMenuView.menuBtn.hidden = YES;
```

and use autolayout constraints (in the interface builder or in the code) between `menuBtn`, `searchbarBtn` and `topMenuView` to make sure your buttons grow as needed.

As a general rule, we should strive to create interface so that views will correctly position themselves provided their inner state is correctly set and correct constraints are formed, without explicit corrections on our part.